# What is a V8Exception error?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm not sure what this error is coming from, nor what it is or what it means. Here is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Now, I am creating an HTML 5 Cross platform (Android/iOS) application using Titanium Studio IDE. I'm not sure if this is an Android specific error or a Titanium Studio specific error. I know it can't be iOS because I only get this error when I am trying to test the app on Android tablet. (The app installs and runs on the device though).

NOTE: The code I am working on is proprietary so I can't show it. But what I'm mostly interested in an explanation of this error. Generally, What is this error and when does some one come across it?

Comment: It's javascript-related.

Comment: Correct. Titanium applications are written in javascript

Comment: ...more specifically, it's related to the V8 engine, the JS engine used by Chrome (and Android).

Comment: V8 is a javascript engine, that error means some of your javascript code caused it to error out, and seeing as it says _"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"_ you have a syntax error in your javascript code

Comment: Oh ok. Googling this has been a bit of a mess for me. Nothing gave me a specific answer except from you guys.

Comment: What about the Unexpected token U? Is the related to the engine? If not, I'm going to assume its my code. If it is related to the engine, can some one please link of a chart of some kind explaining the expected tokens? I feel people reading this could benefit from that.

Comment: Its not related to V8 engine, its related to your code, if you would add your code here, we will get a better picture.